# ORA-00904 while using Hash Partiton in AWS Glue for Oracle Dat Source

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to created Dynamic frame using AWS Glue .
when i try to use additional_options in create dynamic frame i get below error

```
An error occurred while calling o107.getDynamicFrame. ORA-00904: "STANDARD_HASH": invalid identifier
```

This is the syntax i am using to create frame

```
customer_casedfonprem= glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = OnpremOracle, table_name = "_abcd_customer_case", transformation_ctx = "customer_case",additional_options={'hashpartitions': '10','hashfield':'ID'})
customer_casedfonprem.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("customer_caseOnpremView")
```

Same thing is working fine fro Mysql but i get error only when i use this with Oracle tables .
Also when i remove addition option past my glue Job runs fine but it is very very slow .

Comment: looks like your oracle instance doesn't has STANDARD_HASH 
 defined which is required by Glue.What is the version of oracle db?

Comment: 11.2 I also suspect the same thing but is there aby way to make this work ?

Comment: that query creates a slice of your table based on the id field. in this case it will try to make use of the standard_hash. I am assuming your database is below 12c in this case because that functionality is from 12c and above. Check your query history table on the oracle db for the queries fired by glue, if there are there you can try to run them directly on the database.

Comment: @Eman so we do not see any query in Orcale side becasue its a syntax error and job even does not start itself

Comment: Have you tried the version change as this looks is most likely a compatibility issue?